# Increment an integer ever 30 seconds after button press Android

Tags: android

I'm looking for a way to increment an integer every 30 seconds after a button is pressed. The problem I am having is that my code currently waits 30 seconds to increment the integer by 1 but then only one second for every integer after. this is my code.

```
int delay = 5000; // delay for 5 sec.
int period = 30000; // repeat every 30 sec.

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
  public void run() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        if(ammo_remaining<10){
          update_ammo();``
        }
      }
    });
  }
}, delay, period);
```

Comment: Do you use a specific game engine or framework? There may be shortcuts and better ways to do that than with `Timer`s.

Comment: no I didnt, I tried timertask but to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the recursive postdelayed call into your (ammo<10) if statement should give you the behavior you want.

```
    int delay = 5000; // delay for 5 sec.
    int period = 30000; // repeat every 30 sec.
    int ammo_remaining = 10;
    boolean reloading = false;

    Handler handler=new Handler();

    protected void shoot()
        {
        ammo_remaining--;
        update_ammo();
        if( ! reloading) //if not reloading
            {
            reloading = true;
            handler.postDelayed(r, delay);
            }
        }

   Runnable r=new Runnable()
       {
       public void run() 
       {
       if(ammo_remaining<10)
           {
           ammo_remaining++;
           update_ammo();
           handler.postDelayed(r, period);
           }
       else{reloading=false;}
       };
   };
```

edit:

when shooting multiple times, you are creating many instance of the runnable through the handler, that all flood in after the first 30 seconds... you just need to create a boolean flag to keep track of the first request to reload

that 'reloading' flag and check should do the trick...

Comment: Ah that makes sense let me give it a try, I appreciate the help will

Comment: it does the same as before, waiting 30 seconds to increment the first bullet than rapidly restores the rest till it reaches the max of 10

Comment: ahh... when shooting multiple times, you are creating many instance of the runnable throught the handler, that all flood in after the first 30 seconds... you just need to create a boolean flag to keep track of the first request to reload.... i'll put the edits in this answer

Comment: I'm sorry will could you possibly explain that?

Answer (score 0):

Try using handler:

```
    int delay = 5000; // delay for 5 sec.
    int period = 30000; // repeat every 30 sec.
    Handler handler=new Handler();

    protected void your_calling_method() 
        {
        handler.postDelayed(r, delay);
        }

    Runnable r=new Runnable()
        {
        public void run() 
            {
            if(ammo_remaining<10)
                {
                update_ammo();    
                }
            handler.postDelayed(r, period);
            };
        };
```

Comment: it works for the first round, so I hit the button and it reduces the ammo by 1. so lets say I clicked it quickly and took 5 shots the firs shot to be replaced takes 30 seconds but then the rest reload with a second.

Comment: 1 second to re-chamber,10 rounds in clip, 30 seconds to change magazine?  what takes 5 seconds? Be really specific...

Comment: My goal is to have ten shots, when the fire button is pressed, i wanted it to decrease the ammo_remaining integer by 1 and start a timer that would increment the ammo_remaining after 30 seconds of it being shot, so if I shoot 5 rounds in 1 second than every 30 seconds increment ammo_remaining by 1 until it is restored to 10 rounds  (150 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.your button);
    // first get your button;
    final Handler hand = new Handler();


    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            hand.post(new Runnable(){
                @override public void run(){
                    (your int)++; // this will increase your int on step;
                    hand.postDelayed(this,30*1000); // this will do the same thing after 30 seconds again;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```